# ConnectionString for SQL Server Windows Authentification

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, windows-authentication

how can i enable my program to connect to sql database by windows authentification instead of sql authentification with username and password?

Answer (score 0):

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/